# Alpha Channel Makes Sprite Semi-Transparent

Tags: ios, transparency, sprite-kit, alpha

I have a few .png images that I've worked on and brought into SpriteKit and they originally had a "white background" that I've erased. The white background erased fine but the rest of the image is also made "slightly transparent" so that you can see other sprites that are behind it. Im not sure the reasoning for this but I only want the "white background" to be removed while leaving the rest of the picture 100% visible.

The steps I took to get the images are

I drew them in "Microsoft Paint"
Then I put them on a flash drive and bring them to my Mac
I open them in "Preview" and manually erase any area I don't want to be visible.
Then Drag them into SpriteKit

The result is that the area that I erased is now gone, but the rest of the image is somewhat see-through as well, and it should not be.

Any help is Appreciated!

In SpriteKit I've set the SKNode alpha to 1, but this doesn't seem to help at all.

Here Is A Picture Of The Problem - you can see the nodes behind the fish.

[image]

Comment: Any pictures of the symptoms?

Comment: just posted a pic, its directly related to the alpha channel, if i import the picture with the "white background" still on the picture, then this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: try changing blendMode, otherwise use a better image tool. Seashore for OS X is free and easy to use.

Comment: Even the OSX Preview app's editor will work well.

Comment: I used Seashore and no longer have the problem, thanks! "Preview" must be a little sloppy, wish they would fix that tho.

Comment: Weird, I use Preview for this and it works perfectly fine. I suppose you might've selected all white from the picture and removed it (this would explain the transparency).